# fopen "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!" sometimes

Tags: php, cross-domain, fopen

So I am doing some PHP Corss-Origin Processing and Tunneling. On a remote server I have a PHP compiling some files which can take a while depending on the requested files. From another server I do the following:

```
$file = "http://".$remote."/remote.php?prj=".$getprj;
$filename = substr($file,strrpos($file,"/")+1);
$fp = fopen($file, "r") or die("DEAD");
if(!headers_sent())
{
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#86554
//  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; "
.sprintf('filename="%s"; ', rawurlencode($filename))
.sprintf("filename*=utf-8''%s", rawurlencode($filename)));
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
//  header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
}
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.

while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
}
fclose($fp);
```

When I put in one request, after several seconds it provides me with a download. When I put in another request, after a slightly longer while it comes back with the above error.

```
Warning: fopen(http://that.remote.server/remote.php?prj=tnt3): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /.../current.php on line 18 DEAD
```

I am almost suspecting a timeout, but without being able to `set_time_limit` I cannot be sure of that. What are my options here?

Answer (score -1):

In the error message, "current.php" is the file are you trying to open or is part of other URI? Because this "..." looks strange...

Comment: You should include this in comments

Comment: @Emeeus He doesn't have enough reputation for comments.   @Fran the `current.php` is the one with the `fopen`. The `/.../` is the absolute path from customers, numbers, httpd, etc which I omitted.